# How to stop deep learning speech model to not recognize stranger voice?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, python-3.x

I am trying to figure it out. But I can't find any solution. My model accuracy is 99% and my testing accuracy is 98%

I am using softmax for multiclass classification and adam optimizer to reach its final value.

I am collecting mfccs and other features of the stranger's voice. But my model does its best to give a label to a stranger's voice. I don't want that. Should I increase the label size by 1 for strangers? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

98% is too high: Your model might overfit actually. Did you apply a drop out of 0.1 or 0.2?

On the other hand, is your model trained on stranger voices?

Otherwise, if there is no existing training for stranger voices, it will systematically try to assign any input to an existing one.

Stranger voices should be assigned to a label and as a consequence to data containing many different stranger voices or even noise.

Of course, all stranger voices should be quite different from the familiar ones, otherwise, you will have wrong results.

Comment: maybe worth mention that he should also change the final layer and the loss, since this is no more multinomial distribution, but a multinomial and a bernoulli, thefore he need 2 final layers, a softmax and a sigmoid, and the loss as $L = CrossEntropy(softmax) + BinCrossEntropy(sigmoid)$